# "Access Denied" error during TFS XAML build process

Tags: tfs, msbuild, tfsbuild

I Have Source Controller And Team Project  My Build Process Is 
[image: Build Proccess]

and when i build i Got Access Denied Error Like This:
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\bin\amd64\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets (3678): Unable to copy file "C:\Builds\2\AcuatAgile\AcuatNFSBuild\src\AcuatAgile\Release001\Library\Kendo.Mvc.dll" to "C:\Builds\2\AcuatAgile\AcuatNFSBuild\bin\Kendo.Mvc.dll". Access to the path 'C:\Builds\2\AcuatAgile\AcuatNFSBuild\bin\Kendo.Mvc.dll' is denied.

and every time i got Access Denied To Different File DLL 
I Searched The Net And Most Of The Answers are Clean WorkSpace As You Can See I Put True To Clean WorkSpace And I Got The Same Error in Build.
is there any other parameters to solve this problem?

Comment: Do you have your `\bin` folder in source control?

Comment: As @Daniel mentioned do you have your "C:\Builds\2\AcuatAgile\AcuatNFSBuild\bin\" folder checked-in to TFS? I believe this is the case, so please check this answer here : http://stackoverflow.com/a/24065202/1766402

Comment: I Check The Bin Folder It was Not Checked in To Source Controller

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Check the properties of bin folder to see whether it is read-only.
2. Try to add the following MSBUILD arguments in the build definition: `/m:1` to make MSBUILD to use only one process to build.

Comment: Thankyou Solution Number 2 Is Working For Me I Added Arguments